# Migrating controller class that extends SimpleFormController to @Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, controller

I have to migrate my Spring 3 to Spring 5. In Spring 3 *SimpleFormController* is already deprecated, in newer versions is missing altogether, the reason is that annotation based controller configuration is strongly encouraged. So say I have the following class:

```
public class SpecificController extends SimpleFormController {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = super.handleRequestInternal(request, response);
        // set all sorts of things on modelAndView object
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

**How could I rewrite this class with this method to be annotation based?**

The part

```
// set all sorts of things on modelAndView object
```

is really important, so manipulating the resulted modelAndView object is essential.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: Yes. You annotate the SpecificController with @Controller/@RestController. You set @RequestMapping for both the class and the method, you can override ParameterizableViewController, if you wish, and instead of getting ModelAndView via super's call, you create a new one.